# Safari animation (keyframes and transform) set wrong positions

Tags: css, safari, css-animations, css-transforms, mobile-webkit

I have a weird issue only on Safari (strange? LOL). Doesn't matter if you are on iPhone, iPad or Desktop Mac; **Safari** makes a wrong calculation positioning a logo, using **animation keyframes and transform**.

The issue is that logo needs to move to his room, but on safari the logo goes **too to the left**, and when the keyframes reach 100% the logo fits on his room perfectly.

You can see the weird effect on: https://amonarraiz.com (visit on Safari is different than visit on another browser, the code is the same).

Here is my code:

```css
.intro-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.intro-logo {
  background: url(https://amonarraiz.com/css/img/slider/2.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 41rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-86%, -52%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-86%, -52%);
  transform: translate(-86%, -52%);
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.intro-in {
  -moz-animation-duration: 3.75s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3.75s;
  animation-duration: 3.75s;
  -moz-animation-name: intro-in;
  -webkit-animation-name: intro-in;
  animation-name: intro-in;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-moz-keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
  }
}

@keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
    transform: translate(-106%, -46%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-wrapper">
  <div class="intro-logo intro-in"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know what is the problem here. All browsers render it perfectly (including Google Chrome's emulator), but Safari (iOS / Mac) is unable to render it in the right way while the animation is running (when animation ends, the logo sit on his room).

If you need more details, please, tell me and I add them as soon as possible.

Thank you.

### Edit

I will add a bounty because this have no enough attention

Comment: I thought I was going insane trying to understand where this bug came from - animation and transforms seems to be the problem. Thanks for posting your question.

Comment: You're welcome, that's a weird issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `translate` with percentage values, which calculates the element's position according to its width and height. But width and height also changes with the animation. In my opinion, this might be a Safari bug where it calculates the translate according to initial width and height.

You have two workarounds to choose. Use `scale` while transforming or use a concrete unit for distance. If you want to use scale though, you have to change some numbers, I am not sure how exactly it works though.

If you use `rem` instead of percentage in your animation, it works:

```css
.intro-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.intro-logo {
  background: url(https://amonarraiz.com/css/img/slider/2.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 41rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.intro-in {
  -moz-animation-duration: 3.75s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3.75s;
  animation-duration: 3.75s;
  -moz-animation-name: intro-in;
  -webkit-animation-name: intro-in;
  animation-name: intro-in;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@-moz-keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
  }
}
@keyframes intro-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 41rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
    transform: translate(-25rem, -21.5rem);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 25.6rem;
    height: 19.5rem;
    -ms-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
    transform: translate(-27.136rem, -8.97rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intro-wrapper">
  <div class="intro-logo intro-in"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh my God, with fixed units all works fine. Safari bugs are annoying. This is the good candidate to get the bounty. However, can you tell me if this could cause issues depending on the screen resolution? I did the code with percentages to avoid the problem on all screen resolutions. If you can confirm that, you'll get 150 reputation points of bounty. You can test the final result with your code on https://amonarraiz.com

Comment: One question: can you upvote my post? Is to compensate the reputation spent :) thank you!!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The percentages are not needed. You use `rem` (relative em) units which are relative to its parent's font size. You should have no problem in other resolutions or other font sizes. Regarding this bug in Safari, I would report it but I don't have an apple device to verify it in Safari's latest version.

Comment: I confirm you this works perfectly.  I'm aware if this can cause an issue in other browsers, but in my firsts tests all is OK. I understand how `rem` works, but I did not imagine this can be solve the problem. I use percentages because the sizes could be bigger or smaller depending on screen resolutions. Thank you so much for this good solution. The bounty is for you :)